# Learning Python the Hard Way: Exercise 19

Tags: python

Just started learning python with Zed Shaw's book. In one of the exercises with `def function` want to use `raw_input` and don't know how to achieve this. Any help and advice appreciated.

When running code I'm getting this error:

```
 File "drills19.py", line 27, in <module>
    boys_and_girls(boys, girls)
  File "drills19.py", line 2, in boys_and_girls
    print "In your school there are %d boys." % boys_count
TypeError: %d format: a number is required, not str
```

Regards, Alex

```
def boys_and_girls(boys_count, girls_count):
    print "In your school there are %d boys." % boys_count
    print "In your school there are %d girs." % girls_count
    print "Total number of students in the school is %d." % (boys_count + girls_count)
    print "That's a lot of students!\n"
print "How many boys on the school?"
boys = raw_input(">")
print "How many girls in the school?"
girls = raw_input(">")
boys_and_girls(boys, girls)
```

Comment: "Just started learning python with Zed Shaw's book" that book is very old, and it's teaching you a version of Python that is no longer supported. I _strongly_ urge you to find a resource for learning Python 3.6 or later, ideally version 3.8.

Comment: Are you sure you want to learn the outdated Python 2?

Comment: Hey Chris, thanks for the reply. Any recommendations on the resources?

Comment: Off-site recommendations are off-topic here as defined in the [help/on-topic], but I always start [at the source](https://www.python.org/about/gettingstarted/).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `raw_input` returns an `str` (i.e. a string), but the `%d` format type expects a number. You can convert it to a number using `int()`:

```py
...
boys = int(raw_input(">"))
...
girls = int(raw_input(">"))
...
```

Comment: Thanks a million!

Answer (score 0):

Whatever input you give as user input, it is received as `string` by default.

In the print statement you are specifying that you would be printing an integer value (`%d` in print statement) but then again you are passing `string` value which was stored from user input.

You need to convert the raw_input into integer first.

Try this :

```
def boys_and_girls(boys_count, girls_count):
    print "In your school there are %d boys." % boys_count
    print "In your school there are %d girs." % girls_count
    print "Total number of students in the school is %d." % (boys_count + girls_count)
    print "That's a lot of students!\n"

print "How many boys on the school?"
boys = int(raw_input(">"))
print "How many girls in the school?"
girls = int(raw_input(">"))
boys_and_girls(boys, girls)
```

Comment: Thanks a million!

Comment: Great I could help.  Please dont forget to upvote and mark answer as accepted if it helped. :)  Cheers brother.